# Project setup help: Siemens S7-1200 with Modbus and OPC UA

Tags: plc, modbus

I'm currently planning a PLC project but I'm not sure how to put the components together.

About my setup:
I want to integrate a Siemens S7-1200 as master PLC.
The PLC should control a subordinate control via Modbus/TCP (= Modbus Client).
In addition, an OPC UA server should also run on the PLC, which sends sensor data to an edge gateway.
The PLC should also have 4 digital inputs and outputs.

I am now stumped on choosing the right S7 central processing unit. Is the PLC 1215C sufficient for this purpose?

The PLC has two PROFINET ports.

Comment: I think that the [Siemens automation forum](https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/ww/en/conf/35/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search in Siemens industry mall show OPC/UA is an optional add-on, so yes, 1215C can be configured to use it.

SIMATIC OPC UA S7-1200 Basic
6ES7823-0BA00-2BA0